# MS Word Content Controls - how to remove them enmasse

Tags: ms-word

One of my team members edits MS-Word documents. Whenever he does the document is littered with content controls. This is driving me loony. I would like to edit the document, not fight with content controls.

How do I remove all of them from the doc? Preferably without a round trip to plain text and back?

Bonus round: How can I disable them permanently in the word doc?

Comment: This is off-topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic It would be better posted in Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or another help forum about using Word. -- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/ -- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=threads&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&tm=1473637240674 --- I believe macropod has answered your question, though. I am curious. How is it you have to fight with content controls?

Comment: Charles as noted below I posted here only after doing a search on StackExchange. Most MS-Word questions are posted here, so I asked. @macropod has since pointed out that MSAnswers would have been a better choice.    Content Controls and their pain. One team member's editing tool leaves content controls every few words and spaces. To delete a single extra space first I need to remove the control and then do the editing. Rinse and repeat. For document still in the early stages of writing this can be maddening. I suspect the problem is Word in a webbrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove:

1. Ctrl+A (select all)
2. Right click > Remove Content Control

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Context menu -> Remove Content Control didn't exist 2yrs when I was first suffering this disease.

Comment: Downvoting this because it doesn't work for me.  I opened a MS-provided template full of content controls, pressed Ctrl+A, and when I right-clicked, the selction disappeared and the context menu did not contain the Remove Content Control option.  It only shows up if I right-click a single paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Simply save the document in the older .doc format. Since the .doc format doesn't support content controls, that's as near as you can get to disabling them permanently.

BTW: Questions on general Word usage are off-topic for Stack Overflow

A macro that can delete all content controls from a docx/docm document while preserving their displayed content without affecting the use of features introduced in Office 2007 & later is:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument
  Do While .ContentControls.Count > 0
    .ContentControls(1).Delete
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Clever. Only downside is that I lose other features at the same time. If off topic here, where to ask? I search on the stackexchange and the original stackoverflow is where most word questions get asked. Open to a better location.

Comment: More appropriate sites would be MS Answers, StackExchange, msofficeforums.com, etc.  Re-saving in the docx format would restore access to the newer features, though any you've already employed might likewise have been lost. See updated answer for just deleting the content controls from a docx/docm document.

Comment: Downvoting this because it does not "presere their displayed content".  I opened a MS-provided template full of content controls and ran this macro.  It deleted all of the displayed text in the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get rid of the content controls by converting the document to .doc format and then converting back to docx. You do lose the formula fields and stuff, but that is minor convenience. The reason why that happened is because my villain used Google Docs for editing the document. If you conver the word file to .xml, you may be able to identify what these sdt represent.

Comment: Sorry that's too extreme for me since you lose all other docx benefits.

Comment: True. I suspect that the client was possibly using the Google Docs Track Changes feature and then downloading the document as .docx. I have not tried reproducing it. However, I have had this problem working with Japanese clients almost always.

Comment: In my case I eventually figured out they were using MS Word online.

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me.